# Errors while installing 19.10 on Adata NVME SSD (blk_update_request: operation not supported error)

Tags: ssd, 19.10, nvme

My Adata SSD was showing 100% health in Adata toolbox on Windows right prior installing Ubuntu.

During installation and after system was installed, I see those errors spamming in system log all the time:

> blk_update_request: operation not supported error, dev nvme0n1, sector 332458505 op 0x9:(WRITE_ZEROES) flags 0x0 phys_seg 0 prio class 0

those errors are all the same, just different numbers each time

Other than that, I don't see any major system instability, but this error looks very suspicious to me. Also, I have > 3000 of such errors in error log, and it is even before 1 hour passed since I've installed the system. System log became very slow.

Smart log:

> sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1 Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1
>   namespace-id:ffffffff critical_warning                    : 0
>   temperature                         : 57 C available_spare
>   : 100% available_spare_threshold           : 10% percentage_used
>   : 3% data_units_read                     : 8 319 440
>   data_units_written                  : 13 561 180 host_read_commands
>   : 143 158 056 host_write_commands                 : 257 546 141
>   controller_busy_time                : 2 038 power_cycles
>   : 377 power_on_hours                      : 6 990 unsafe_shutdowns
>   : 314 media_errors                        : 0 num_err_log_entries
>   : 646 131 Warning Temperature Time            : 428 Critical Composite
>   Temperature Time : 0 Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0 Thermal
>   Management T2 Trans Count   : 0 Thermal Management T1 Total Time    :
>   0 Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0

In nvme error log I see this:

> Error Log Entries for device:nvme0n1 entries:64 ................. 
>   Entry[ 0]    ................. error_count  : 647085 sqid         : 1
>   cmdid        : 0x1 status_field : 0x4004(INVALID_FIELD: A reserved
>   coded value or an unsupported value in a defined field) parm_err_loc :
>   0xffff lba          : 0x12108f0e nsid         : 0x1 vs           : 0
>   cs           : 0 .................

Btw, it doesn't appear in 18.04 LTS.

Does anybody know what is this? And how to fix that?

PS: Looks like enabling "Windows 7 installation mode" in my MSI motherboard BIOS made those errors go away completely!

Comment: Have you checked if Adata has a firmware update. Many SSD need that. The Windows 7 mode would be turning UEFI Secure Boot off. Also MSI UEFI update may be required.

Comment: Yes, I have latest available firmware

Comment: Most Windows 7 installs were BIOS. And original ISO was configured for BIOS. Update to Windows 7 ISO then included the UEFI boot option by adding /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is what UEFI boots from. Original ISO can be copied to flash drive & modified to UEFI boot. But Windows 7 expires Jan 2020, so not much need anymore for Windows 7.  Many new systems with UEFI have Secure Boot mode. Windows 7 does not support Secure boot, so that also must be off.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling "Windows 7 installation mode" in my MSI motherboard BIOS made those errors go away completely

Comment: So you're saying that using BIOS instead of UEFI solved it? Sounds like UEFI firmware issues, check for BIOS/firmware update for your motherboard

Comment: Having latest BIOS and SSD firmware