# My SSD still shows it's full, although I've deleted (no trashed) 60 GB?

Tags: ssd, disk-usage, amd-ryzen

I have a new PC (AMD Ryzen 2800X, MSI Mortar Max, and so).
A friend of mine posted [a question about this setup on AMD forums](https://community.amd.com/thread/253637).

The behavior is:

- ~/.xsession-errors fills up my /home partition (60 GB). Completely. After like 1 hour.
- Applications start behaving weird, because they run out of diskspace (e.g. gkrellm loses its config.)
- I delete ~/.xsession-errors. Now some applications (ls, baobab) show me there's only 19GB used - the rest should be free(d). But "df" or Thunar say: 0 Bytes free.
- I already dd-copied the original (Kingston) SSD to my old (=running flawlessy!) SSD (PNY) - but now the behavior is still the same.

I thought it was related to suspend/resume, but that only caused the X session to stay alive long enough to fill the .xsession-errors file. That file, btw, contains an infinite number of strange GTK or X warnings - but the GUI is behaving fine.

I already ran "[debsums](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/debsums.1.html)" to check if my system data is fine - and all packages returned "OK".

Does anyone have any idea where I could continue to catch that Gremlin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you reboot or restart the session? Removing an open file will not liberate the space until it is closed.

Comment: I would look inside the file for what messages are filling the log.. You haven't provided OS/release details, nor the message/warning itself,  but i'd see the messages themselves as your greatest clue  (eg. a terminal `fgrep` looking for [source] programs that spit out that message for clues etc)

Comment: What brand/model motherboard. Some need settings to prevent run away log files. Have you updated UEFI to latest available, that may also help? MSI w/Adata SSD needs Windows 7 mode to stop log file errors
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194233/errors-while-installing-19-10-on-adata-nvme-ssd-blk-update-request-operation-n MSI x299 SLI Also acpi=off boot parameter
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2371556

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to provide OS/release details: Xubuntu 18.04.4 (64bit)

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: Oh! Good point. xsession-errors of course is still open. Okay, so it's not an SSD/kernel issue and it's "okay" that the freed space is still allocated. Thanks!

And yes: After a reboot, everything's back to normal (until xsession-errors overflows again)

Comment: I'll try to post some messages from xsession-errors. I haven't done that yet, because (a) they seem to appear across several completely different applications, and (b) because I've symlinked xsession-errors to /dev/null as a workaround so I can use that machine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Weird: I know I had the issue *after* I replaced my SSD, but right now my xsession-errors behaves normally, and also suspend/resume works. I was hoping for this to work - seems it does.
I didn't backup the 60+ GB xsession-errors, and now it stays small (luckily).

I'll keep an eye on it.

btw, here's info about which SSD/firmware version definitely had issues, so xsession-errors grew out of bounds, because some data didn't find it's way back sometimes:

- Model Number:   KINGSTON SV300S37A120G
- Firmware Revision:   603ABBF0

Firmware update 60AABBF0 is available, but requires a bare-metal Windows machine:
https://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/downloads/90683

Thanks for your help!
Especially the hint about "*deleting open files won't free the diskspace*".

Comment: Hmpf. Cheered too soon:
Still random application crashes/errors, but I've found out that "debsums -s" shows faulty package files that stay broken (hashcode mismatch) until I reboot: Then they're back to their original, bit-exact state. This would also explain why xsession-errors goes wild "sometimes", because the data (or binary) of some application goes bad after suspend/resume. I'll try to deactivate the disk cache and see if that changes something...

Answer (score 0):

Update, in case someone runs into similar issue(s):
The weird behavior is a combination of separate things.

- ~/.xsession_errors was filled by Nextcloud client. See: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/glib-gio-critical-g-menu-insert-item-assertion-g-is-menu-menu-failed/80916
- Although memtest86+ reported no errors through several 4/4 passes at different times, one of the RAM modules seems to be bad. Leaving only 1 RAM module in at a time greatly improved narrowing it down. "Debsums -s" was usually more reliably to detect errors than memtest in this case.

Today I finally have screenshots of memtest failing on the suspicious RAM module! So I can send it in for replacement.